# avatarURL has a strange issue with Users

Tags: discord, discord.js

So when trying to make my Discord.js bot display an User Avatar, it works with other bots but not with actual users, I have this problem on all commands that use user.avatarURL

This is the code I am using

```
const user = message.mentions.users.first();
if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(`${prefix}av`)){
        let member = message.mentions.members.first(); 
      if(member){
          const emb=new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          emb.setAuthor(`${user.username}'s avatar`, user.avatarURL())
          emb.setImage(user.avatarURL());
          message.channel.send(emb)
          
      }
      else{
          message.channel.send("Sorry none found with that name")
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please specify your problem?

Comment: If I use the command on a user, anyone who is not a bot it returns blank profile pictures, however if I use it on a Bot user, any bot user It will work the way its intended to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use displayAvatarURL instead, with the optional dynamic option.

```js
emb.setAuthor(`Text`, user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }));
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=displayAvatarURL

Comment: I tried this but the issue is that it only displays a bot avatar, I can't seem to get it to display a User avatar

Comment: Some other code I was using to edit user nicknames was causing problems with that particular command, thanks for the help though!